# Get data related to logged user from web api using Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, api-authorization

I cannot figure out safe way to get only data linked to authenticated users using ASP.net core web api and Angular (PWA).

I tried 

1. MSAL inside Angular and called an API function with login ID but Java based client codes do not seem to be safe or I could be wrong.

http.get('https://api.abc.edu/api/students/11223@abc.edu) -->11223 is parent login.

2. I tried alternative inside the web api to get login ID then call a database to get data.

   var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("preferred_username").Value;

In Angluar way:

```
getItems(parentID: string): Observable<ParentStudent[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiEndpointParentStudents + "/" + parentID)  //parentID is a logged user name from Azure called from Angular.
      .map((response: Response) =>
        response
      )
      .catch(response => (Observable.throw(response)
      ))
  }
```

in webapi way:

```
startup.cs
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Inject default DB connection string.
            services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddAzureAdBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.AddProtectWebApiWithMicrosoftIdentityPlatformV2(Configuration);
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest);
            services.AddCors();

            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>(); // find a login user.            
            //services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddTransient<IUserResolverService, UserResolverService>();

            services.AddMvc();
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
         ---- 
         app.UseAuthentication();
        ------
}
StudentsController.cs
 [HttpGet]        
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Student>>> GetStudents()
        {

 var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("preferred_username").Value;
                return await _context.Students.Where(t => t.ParentLoginUsername == userId || t.ParentLoginUsername == userId).ToListAsync();
        }
```

Both worked fine but for security, among my above solutions, should the webapi based solution be considered first over any client based solutions such as Angular? Can hackers , another parents or another bank customers (if my PWA is a banking app) call api with other persons’ user id in Angular or postman once they got auth id and auth token?

Comment: What do you mean as "msal .. Java based client codes do not seem to be safe"? Could you please share your experience?

Comment: The source is exposed in Java based client applications. If a source from a web site is tempered, then the web server will refuse the request from the tempered one. But PWA is itself a web server alike? Therefore I guess hackers could play with the source code? I am not an expert though. could another parents with id=1111 send a request with 'id=1124' to get other students' details. Can it be possible?